# Is there a way to run C++ and Java files with limited privileges?

Tags: java, c++, unix

I have to run other people's compiled code on my Ubuntu server and I am worried that the source code is potentially harmful (System privileges, deletes files, that sort of thing). Is it possible to limit the things they are allowed to do from the terminal?

Comment: It's not a matter of the language these executables were build from, but which account they run from.

Comment: Various sandboxing options are available but these require expertise to achieve your security goals. It is really too broad of a question for SO, and at best only peripherally programming related.

Comment: This question might be on topic in http://askubuntu.com/ or http://superuser.com/ Search them for an existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can run Java programs under a [SecurityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) which can allow or block different kinds of operations, regardless of which user the program is being run by.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is sandboxing, your question a slightly broad, anyway:

You can use `chroot` to limit the view of the system to a restricted portion of the filesystem. This is light sandboxing. `chroot` command is available on many Unixes.

On OSX you have a `sandbox-exec` command that can be used to defines more precisely the privileges of the process.

On Linux you have a equivalent called `AppArmor` which also use privileges specification for your processes.

Answer (score -1):

Limit their privileges; if you run a Java program as root, than it will have root privileges.  If you run a program and have no privileges, the program will have no privileges.

Comment: You don't need to be root to find all the files in the directory in erase them.

Comment: Than _don't give the user privileges to do that._

Comment: which is what I am asking in the first place. HOW to do that

Comment: Oh, okay.  That's not a Java matter; you need to change privileges from the command line, using `chmod` or similar tools.